# tensorboard: command not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I installed TensorFlow on my MacBook Pro 10.12.5 from source code by steps described here.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

TensorFlow itself works well but I cannot run TensorBoard.
It seems tensorboard is not installed properly.

When I try running `tensorboard --logdir=...` it says `-bash: tensorboard: command not found`. And `locate tensorboard`  returns empty.

Do I need any additional step to install tensorboard?

Comment: This error can also appear if TensorFlow has been installed in a virtualenv or Conda environment and the environemnt is currently not loaded.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**If no other methods work then try this one. It may help you**.
 
1. check the location of Tensorflow

```
pip show tensorflow
```

It will show output something like this.

...

*Name: tensorflow

Version: 1.4.0*

*Location: /home/abc/xy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages*

...

2. Go to that location you get from the above output.

```
cd /home/abc/xy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

There you can see a directory named tensorboard.

```
cd tensorboard
```

3. There must be a file named 'main.py'.

4. Execute the following command to launch the tensorboard.

```
python main.py --logdir=/path/to/log_file/
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: In order to don't execute this procedure more than once. I just added at .bashrc the following command:
tensorboard() {
  cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard && python main.py --logdir=/PATH/training
}

so everytime I wanna execute it I just run the command tensorboard. It worked like a charm btw. Thanks

Comment: But what if there is no `main.py`? That's the case for me on tensorflow 1.14.0 installed with conda.

Comment: @Aposhian In that case, uninstall the package and try with pip install tensorboard. It worked for me.

Answer (score 56):

You could call `tensorboard` as a python module like this:

```
python3 -m tensorboard.main --logdir=~/my/training/dir
```

or add this to your .profile

`alias tensorboard='python3 -m tensorboard.main'`

Comment: Thank you. That way is easier than search, change directory and run from the specific location.

Answer (score 6):

**If you installed Tensorflow with Virtualenv, then first Check whether you have activated the tensorflow envirnoment or not**

If you have activated the tensorflow session then your command prompt will look like this :

[image: tensorflow command prompt]

If not, Write the below command and try running **tensorboard** again.

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

[image: tensorboard running]

Answer (score 3):

Run this command:

```
python3 -m tensorboard.main --logdir=logdir
```

To run directory you can use,

Change =logdir to ="dir/TensorFlow"
(Directory path)

Answer (score 2):

What version of Tensorflow are you running? Older versions don't include Tensorboard.

If you do have a newer version, I see you are using OSX, which apparently caused some problems for other people: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2115 Check this page to fix it!

> As a MacPorts user, I'm used to running things from out of the path
>   /opt/local/bin. When you install a python package via MacPorts, that's
>   where the executables go --- even if they're just symbolic links to
>   files to a main python repository in
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/
>
> pip installs things into the latter directory, but apparently does NOT
>   add the symbolic link to /opt/local/bin
>
> This has never been an issue (or even come up) for me before, because
>   I've only used pip to install (non-executable) packages which load
>   from within python. In conclusion, there is a
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/tensorboard
>
> This is a pip / MacPorts-SOP mismatch / user error*, and nothing to do
>   with tensorboard in particular. Please close this issue. Thanks for
>   your help.
>
> *my 'locate' database was in the process of updating but hadn't completed

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using 1.2.1. I read it but it seems different to my current problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pycharm in windows environment this may help:
`python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=logs`

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution -

`echo "alias tensorboard='python3 -m tensorboard.main'" >> ~/.bash_profile`

After adding this to your .bash_profile you can use

`tensorboard --logdir=/path`