# How to run tensorboard in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tensorboard

Whenever I try to run tensorboard in a jupyter notebook within visual studio code with this command `tensorbard --logdir=runs`, I get the message `Launching TensorBoard...`. However, Tensorboard never launches. Sometimes I also get an error message.

Any ideas on how to launch tensorboard within vscode?

**EDIT:**

I also tried running slightly optimized commands

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir runs
```

but this only shows the message `Launching Tensorboard...` eternally.

Same result with

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir runs --host localhost --port 8888
```

Is there any tensorboard extension that embeds tensorboard into a cell output?

Comment: I wish tensorboard was supported by a VSCode extension :(

Comment: @pcko1 It is now integrated into VSCode.

Comment: In October 2023 this still doesn't work even with the VSCode integration, if you work via SSH on a remote machine with Conda. You either get a prompt for "Tensorboard not installed" or a timeout after 60 seconds. I followed all the VSCode GitHub bug issues on this issue, and they all end up pointing out to this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/19592 which actually didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I now fixed the issue on my end with this procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301753/3873799

Answer (score 28, accepted):

VS Code and the Python extension now has TensorBoard integrated in it in its latest release!

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-february-2021-release/

To start a TensorBoard session from VSC:

1. Open the command palette (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P)
2. Search for the command “Python: Launch TensorBoard” and press enter.
3. You will be able to select the folder where your TensorBoard log
   files are located. By default, the current working
   directory will be used.

VSCode will then open a new tab with TensorBoard and its lifecycle will be managed by VS Code as well. This means that to kill the TensorBoard process all you have to do is close the TensorBoard tab.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer and the release announcement may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28410596)

Comment: The VSCode + Python extension + TensorBoard doesn't work. It worked for a while in a VM on GCS, but then it stopped working. Wasted 4 hours on work trying and only downgrading python extension solved it. A week later same issue and no version would work. When launching TensorBoard a pop-up says I need to install it. Then it can't find Conda. If I change to the base Conda environment it manages to find Conda and install (although it already was installed with tensorflow 2.7), but I still can't launch it. I just get the same message about needing to install TensorBoard. It is a waste of time.

Comment: my tensorboard times out after 60 seconds when i try following these steps.

Comment: In October 2023 this still doesn't work even with the VSCode integration, if you work via SSH on a remote machine with Conda. You either get a prompt for "Tensorboard not installed" or a timeout after 60 seconds. I followed all the VSCode GitHub bug issues on this issue, and they all end up pointing out to this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/19592 which actually didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I now fixed the issue on my end with this procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301753/3873799

Answer (score 8):

You can use this

```
tensorboard --logdir=data/ --host localhost --port 8888
```

Comment: If you run this command as a magic inside notebook, you will have to physically open a browser and type in url `http//localhost:8888` to see the dashboard.

Answer (score 7):

Although the answer provided by @Jeffrey is correct, it lacks an important detail. Since I am not able to edit the post from @Jeffrey, I am rewriting my answer here.

You have to select python interpreter from `Command Palette` -> `Python Select Interpreter` as mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) **BEFORE using the 3 steps mentioned in the Jeffrey's post.**

Additionally, VS Code might ask you to install **tensorboard** and **torch-tb-profiler** before third step mentioned in Jeffrey's post. You could install it by clicking on the prompt or manually.

Hence, the comprehensive steps will be as follows:

1. **Select appropriate python interpreter**: `Command Palette` -> `Python Select Interpreter`
2. **Start Tensorboard**: `command palette` -> `Python: Launch TensorBoard`
3. (For first time) **Install [Tensorboard](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-tensorboard/) and torch-tb-profiler**: You can do it by just clicking on vs code prompt or manually inside the select python interpreter.
4. **Folder selection**: Select the folder where your TensorBoard log files are stored. By default, the current directory opened in vs code file will be used.

References:
[1](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters
[2](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-tensorboard/): https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-tensorboard/

Comment: Thankyou very much `You have to select python interpreter` , its not enough to declare the env on the config

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was able to visualize tensorboard by entering `http://localhost:6006` in the browser.

Screenshot of Tensorboard
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In October 2023 the VSCode integration still didn't work for me out of the box, when attempting to use it via SSH on a remote machine with Conda.
I either got a prompt for `Tensorboard not installed` or a timeout after 60 seconds. If I selected "Yes" when I got Tensorboard not installed, I got an installation process started, at the end of which I got the message `All requested packages are already installed`. I followed all the VSCode GitHub bug issues on this issue, and they all end up pointing out to this PR: github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/19592 which actually didn't fix the issue for me.

tl;dr: what I did to run Tensorboard via SSH on my Ubuntu VM was:

1. Check if you can start tensorboard manually running `tensorboard --logdir= .`  from terminal without getting a `command not found` or similar error.

   1.1 If not, check if you tensorboard installation has a `main.py` file, as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47715665/3873799):

   - check the location of Tensorflow: `pip show tensorflow`
   - `cd` to the location printed on screen.
   - `cd tensorboard` to go in the main code folder
   - `ls` and verify if there is a `main.py` file.

   1.2 If no `main.py` is present, probably the installation got corrupted. Make sure you don't have the deprecated `tensorflow-tensorboard` installed:

   - run `pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard`,
   - uninstall and reinstall tensorboard: `pip uninstall tensorboard`
   - reinstall: `pip install tensorboard`
2. Here I got an error stating that it couldn't find `GLIBCXX_3.4.29`. I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70990697/3873799) to get it installed.

After 2, I finally could run Tensorboard, even via the VSCode integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
tensorboard --logdir=runs