# Tensorboard loading forever/ not loading in vs code nor in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tensorboard

**Goal**: I want to launch the `tensorboard` dashboard and visualize the loss/metrics in the scalars tab from a generated `tfevents` file there.

**Setup**:
In a `conda` environment, with `python=3.8.5`, with only these packages installed (I created a fresh environment to test the issue, initial code environment used python 3.9):

- `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`
- `conda install ipykernel`
- `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`
- `conda install -c conda-forge tensorboard`
- `pip install torch-tb-profiler`

**Outcome:**
I have an already generated `tfevents` file in the subfolder `runs`. When I use vscode, the now vscode integrated `tensorboard` is loading until timeout. First, I thought its an issue with vs code only...

But I tried to launch tensorboard via the integrated terminal (cmd prompt) with:
`tensorboard --logdir=runs` or `tensorboard --logdir="C:workspace\runs" --host localhost --port 6006`.

Whether in the interactive window in vscode or on `http://localhost:6006/`, in all cases `tensorboard` only opens with the orange header, with a blank page (see image below), loading eternally...

What am I doing wrong here? Its similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938552/how-to-run-tensorboard-in-vscode), but the solution there is not helpful. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT: Thanks to @LzZ, it now magically works even with the above old environment when using the integrated terminal commands but the launch via the command palette still doesnt work in `vscode`**

**EDIT2: Somehow its back to NOT working again in no environment. Something must have unclogged everything yesterday. Now its back to not working...**

**EDIT3: Update: It now works when first calling `tensorboard --logdir dir` in the integrated terminal. Only afterwards, the `%load_ext tensorboard` and `%tensorboard --logdir dir` also work in `vscode` itself.**

[image: when opening tensorboard in a browser or also integrated in vs code this appears]

Answer (score 6):

Try running `pip uninstall torch-tb-profiler` to uninstall the plugin.

You should then be able to run `tensorboard --logdir [name of log directory]` to get tensorboard running.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I already figured that out myself, see my latest edit 3. However, I leave it open so that the devs of vscode see that tensorboard is not launchable directly via their command palette.

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced such issue after installed the PyTorch Profiler Tensorboard plugin, which was recommended by python extension. What I've done to solve this issued is to re-install my conda environment and not to install the PyTorch Profiler Tensorboard plugin.

Comment: Ok, I did that and it now works on `localhost` when opening in browser or within vs code even when not specifying a host and port. Launching tensorboard over the command palette still doesnt work though.

Comment: In the above way, it now works even with old environments that have both `tensorboard` and `tb-torch-profiler`. So the problem might now be `vscode` specific...

Comment: I had the same problem after installing the tb-torch-profiler when offered in VSCode; the tensorboard window loaded the frame but no contents in both VSCode window and in a separate browser window. After reading notes here, I removed torch-tb-profiler with pip uninstall, and the existing tensorboard install (using conda) started working again in VSCode and browser. Maybe there is a problem with VSCode installing the profiler using pip in a conda environment.

Comment: Yeah, but the weird thing is, it now works on my other environment as well where torch-tb-profiler is still installed.

Comment: Thanks! as soon as I removed tb-torch-profiler by typing `pip3 uninstall tb-torch-profiler` it started working (if it says it's not installed, check the output of `which pip`). It seems like they are aware of this issue (https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/issues/270) and hopefully will get resolved soon.