# Tensorboard shows nothing in browser and vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tensorboard

I ran my code and got a tfevent file with log.

and when I ran

```
tensorboard --inspect --logdir Path

find path | grep tfevent
```

They return results without problems

In my environement,
the versions of tensorboard and tensorboardX are 2.5.0 and 2.2

I used `tensorboard --logdir=Path` and it launched in browser. But it showed a blank page with tensorboard logo at top left.

As same as that, I also tried it in vscode by using `tensorboardX` integrated tensorboard abd it showed the same content.

At last, I tried it in Colab and it worked well, meaning that there is no problem for my file.

So I am really confused about the problems about my environment setting.
I will be appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
pip uninstall torch-tb-profiler
```

See more here:
[Tensorboard loading forever/ not loading in vs code nor in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049028/tensorboard-loading-forever-not-loading-in-vs-code-nor-in-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

its probably because tensorboard demands a lot of RAM space,
I've faced the same issue, free the RAM and it'll work.

also if you need to clear tenserboard using <!rm -rf> command, make sure to run `conda install m2-base`. it'll give you all the basic linux commands.