# tensorboard never loads data to visualize

Tags: tensorboard

Somehow my tensorboard instance is no longer loading. When pointing my browser to the right URL, I see the following, but the main portion of the tensorboard UI never loads.

[image]

On another system, tensorboard is able to load the file I'm trying to visualize just fine. I believe there's a cache or configuration file that's corrupted, but I don't know where to find this. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Best,

Chris

Comment: I had a similar problem, and the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078404/tensorboard-shows-nothing-in-browser-and-vscode solved it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did solve the issue, but I really don't understand why. I'll post here if I figure it out.