# Launch Tensorboard command is missing in Command Palette of VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras, tensorboard

I installed tensorboard,
but I dont have that command in command palette:
"Python: Launch TensorBoard". also if I try to get it in that way I found in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938552/how-to-run-tensorboard-in-vscode):
tensorboard --logdir=data/ --host localhost --port 8888

it tell me that:"No dashboards are active for the current data set."
I see the files of logs in my directory.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried all the answers from google, but nothing helped me.
At first, the problem in VS was not solved, but at least I could see the logs with training results.

This is the only helpful command:

```
tensorboard --logdir=./
```

Run it from the directory you run, in which you have the logs directory.

After I run this command, surprisingly, the command: launch tensorboard was also added to commeand palette.