# Tensorboard: TensorFlow installation not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to use tensorboard but i got the following error: TensorFlow installation not found - running with reduced feature set.

i've tried to follow those step: [tensorboard: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095820/tensorboard-command-not-found) but it didn't help me (even when i do cd tensorboard and python main.py i still have this error)

Answer (score 1):

Tensorboard will be automatically installed along with Tensorflow.

```
#create virtual environment
python -m venv --system-site-packages .\venv

#Activate env
.\venv\Scripts\activate
  
#Install Tensorflow
pip install tensorflow

#verify the installation: show packages installed within the virtual environment
pip list
```

Output

```
tensorboard                   2.5.0              
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1              
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.0              
tensorflow                    2.5.0              
tensorflow-datasets           4.0.1              
tensorflow-estimator          2.5.0
```